# PHP printing - Call to undefined function printer_list()

Tags: php, printing, php-extension

I am trying to use PHP's printer functions. But PHP gives an undefined function error. I am using PHP 7.2 so I looked for a php_printer.dll online but I only found for PHP 5.x. I copied it to PHP ext directory and added a line to my php.ini, restarted apache but it still is not working.

I wanted to be able to list all available printers on my network and choose one and print with it.

```
C:\xampp\php\ext\php_printer.dll
```

**php.ini**

```
extension=php_printer.dll
```

Here is my code

```
$ouput = 'Test print...';

$getprt = printer_list( PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL | PRINTER_ENUM_SHARED );
$handle = printer_open(getprt['NAME']);

 if($handle) {
      echo "connected";
 } else {
      echo "not connected";    
 }

printer_set_option($handle, PRINTER_MODE, "raw"); 
printer_write($handle,$output);
printer_close($handle);
```

Comment: What does `phpinfo()` show? Does it show the extension as loaded?

Comment: I can't find it in the phpinfo() doesn't show there

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the one issue on that git repo (https://github.com/gimjudge/php) I see that gimjudge has complied these DLL's for 32 PHP only. Their reasoning being that until PHP7 the 64bit PHP versions were actually only experimental. PHP only became truly 64 bit as of PHP7.0

So to use this dll you would have to install the 32bit version of WAMPServer. Then you will probably have no problems activating this DLL.

You can download the 32bit version of WAMPServer 3 from here: http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/
Its the backup repo and much easier to see what you are doing and which version you are downloading than the normal SourceForge repo.

Make sure you have backed up all you site(s) and databases before installing the 32bit WAMPServer.

However it is possible to install the 32bit AND 64bit WAMPServer on the same PC as the default folder names are different (C:\wamp or C:\wamp64) the Apache and MySQL service names are also different (wampapache or wampapache64) and (wampmysqld or wampmysqld64)

Although its not a good idea to start both at the same time as this will use a lot of memory for no good reason.

(Credits RiggsFolly)

Comment: I am using the latest version of XAMPP

Comment: Is that strange that we can't print using PHP 7 64bit?

Comment: I don't think people commonly use php for printing either way.
It's usually done from the front-end, perhaps try using ajax to output your printing goal in a blank page?